# weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.g

Tags: spring, log4j, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am using weblogic version 12c 12.1.3 and I have updated the log4j jar version to log4j-api:2.17.1 log4j-core:2.17.1, but at the time of deployment in weblogic I am getting this error :-

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
               at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
               at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
               Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature
               at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:273)
               at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
               at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
```

Any solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my weblogic.xml file.  Not sure if this will fix your problem but worth a try...

```
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  ...
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
      <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>

    <prefer-application-resources>
      <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
    </prefer-application-resources>
  </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check maven dependencies. It is highly probable to have an indirect dependency for old slf4j-api